# Stream audio to mobile device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'd like to stream the audio from Ubuntu 10.10 to my HTC Desire HD (Android 2.2).

I've seen solutions so far for streaming from audio players, but I'd like to stream any audio output from the PC to my phone.  My use case is for watching TV/Films in VLC or online (BBC iPlayer) in bed, without having to use my surround sound system which is likely to wake up my house mates.  I'm not just talking about music from Banshee, but any audio that the system makes.

I was thinking that PulseAudio is pretty powerful, is it possible to route audio through that to a mobile device?  Can it be done through bluetooth?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Good idea, but consider that streaming audio through a wireless connection (e.g. Bluetooth, Wireless LAN) has a delay a bit too long to enjoy watching TV or video. You could try with pulseaudio remote RTP multicast.

Comment: Yes, you need to search for pulseaudio+bluetooth howtos. I have played some time with pulseaudio sources and sinks — and learned that they can build pretty amazing functional layout. Too bad, I have no bluetooth — so cannot write or even check such a howto.

Comment: PA works directly over TCP/IP too. You just need a client on your phone (no idea if one exists for Android).

Answer (score 4):

While these may not be the options you land on, I'd like to offer you two solutions: One from the 90s (maybe late 80s) and the other from the 1870s (yeah, late nineteenth century technology):

- You could buy some wireless headphones. You can get fairly good enclosed sets for under £50. If quality isn't too much of an issue, halve that number.
- Now we cast back a wee bit further, we hit the granddad of all remote listening: the audio extension cable. These are as cheap as anything and if you have a soldering iron you can buy a stereo spool for almost nothing, add on some pennies for the connectors and wire-up an extended port to your bed.

Both these solutions have next-to-no lag. Obviously the second has less lag but it's a much more hackish solution. I'd just buy some remote headphones and be done with it.

Time (that you might spend looking for the perfect solution) isn't worthless, after all.

Comment: I have considered this and will probably just end up buying wireless headphones, but I was just thinking it would be cool to be able to do it anyway if a ready solution was there without spending any cash!

Answer (score 2):

**SoundWire app**
Download SoundWire Server at http://georgielabs.net/. Depending on your PC operating system choose the Windows 7, Windows XP, Linux 64-bit, or Linux 32-bit version as appropriate.

- [Linux version 32-bit](http://georgielabs.altervista.org/SoundWire_Server_linux32.tar.gz)
- [Linux version 64-bit](http://georgielabs.altervista.org/SoundWire_Server_linux64.tar.gz)

Audio can be streamed using **Wifi, internet**

Answer (score 1):

If your phone can be configured as a sink instead of a source(kinda the problem), and your ubuntu machine as a source(obviously possible) look at "[Can I use my computer as an A2DP receiver / bluetooth speaker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver#_=_)" I was able to do it (but its the other way round) on ubuntu 11.10 and stream my music from the phone to the PC, just to be able to select music while in bed and shut it off wen i want to sleep. the only thing i cant do is adjust volume.
You can stream audio to your phone if it can be a sink, use sound settings under volume control to select your device as output*(assuming you followed that link and got to enable it)* and your PC sound card as input before running the command

> pactl load-module module-loopback

without the source and sink parameters

Answer (score 0):

I once configured an icecast server to broadcast my system sound. All I needed was my IP for my desktop and anything which could pick up my wifi, was an instant sound device.