# How to get my bluetooth-enabled phone to pipe its audio through my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Getting this set up was relatively simple on Windows, but I can't quite figure out how to go about doing it in Ubuntu.

My phone is paired with the Ubuntu machine, and I simply want to pipe the audio from the phone to it. However, I have no idea how to do this.

**Note:** I have [Blueman](https://launchpad.net/blueman) installed, if that helps.

Comment: The top answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver also answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

here u go u should take a look at [**A2DP**](http://jprvita.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/1-2-3-4-a2dp-stream/)