# Using your laptop as loudspeaker for your mobile

Tags: laptop, android, headset

I'm thinking on how to use my laptop running Ubuntu (with its loudspeakers) as "headset" for my Android mobile.
For instance: I listen to some music on my mobile and I want to connect my laptop as a headset!
Is sounds weird maybe but I guess somebody came up with the same idea!
Obviously it deals with bluetooth, how can I display and in case modify the bluetooth services available on ubuntu?

Comment: Probably involves Bluetooth one way or another...

Comment: I forgot to mention it, of course, but how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the top answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver - I tried it now, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could (as alternative) use your Laptop to listen to music and your mobile to control your music program over your mobile with remuco http://code.google.com/p/remuco/