# Is it possible to use Ubuntu as speaker while playing music from a bluetooth-linked smartphone?

Tags: 12.04, sound, bluetooth, smartphone, speakers

Is there a way to use the notebook as speaker for my smartphone? I linked them via Bluetooth and saw that the smartphone can be used as an input-Device for music and sound.

You can see it here:
[image]

My smartphone says that the laptop is linked as an Audio-System. If i play some music on the smartphone, it is recognized by the audio manager. You can see it in the picture, the bar is active and keep moving to the music.
But  i can't hear anything. How can i get this working?

Oh i just forgot:
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 as 64bit on a Lenovo Y560 and the
Smartphone has Android 2.3.6

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my computer as an A2DP receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
 sudo apt-get install blueman
```

and then this:

```
 Bluetooth -v -l device
```

and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Install the `blueman` package and launch Blueman. Now, look for "Advanced Audio Receiver - Experimental Headset Emulation - Very Experimental" in te settings and tick the box. If everything is set up correctly, you can now use your computer as an A2DP sink.

Comment: No effect - doesn't even show up in sound input/output on 14.04.