# No A2DP streaming audio from 12.04 to Bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, headset, a2dp

I want to listen to streaming audio from Ubuntu using headset ([Bose Bluetooth Headset Series 2](http://www.bose.com/controller?url=/shop_online/headphones/mobile_solutions/bluetooth_headset/index.jsp)). Although Bluetooth connection is established, I haven't been able to hear anything via the headset. How can I work this around in general (I know this might sound brutal but I don't have much knowledge in audio setting on linux) ?

When I use my other Bluetooth headset BlueAnt Q2 (http://www.myblueant.com/products/headsets/q2/index.php) streaming is going. In "Hardware" tab on sound setting panel (not sure how it's officially called but see the image below) shows my headset.

[image]

However, Bose one never appears on the same window while it's connected via Bluetooth, except for a few seconds after I manually disconnect the headset (this moment is snapshotted as the image below. When it's connected the Bose BT2 thing is never shown. Btw, with Android phone this headset works just fine).

[image]

[Bose' manual](http://goo.gl/9d5U9) indicates that

```
Make sure the device supports A2DP audio streaming.
```

So I tried to figure out if A2DP is enabled on my Ubuntu (referring to [Can I use my computer as an A2DP receiver / bluetooth speaker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver)), finding that it's probably available as the result below shows:

```
$ sdptool search --bdaddr local a2snk
Searching for a2snk on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00 ...
Service Name: Audio Sink
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "Audio Sink" (0x110b)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 25
  "AVDTP" (0x0019)
    uint16: 0x102
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Advanced Audio" (0x110d)
    Version: 0x0102
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the BOSE headset from known devices in the Bluetooth settings, then put it in **pairing mode** to pair and add it again to your devices?

Comment: @Takkat I'm sure I did on Ubuntu side but am not sure if I did on headset. I'll try

Comment: Install *pavucontrol*, execute (PulseAudioVolumeControl),choose configuration tab once your bluetooth audio device is connected and set the A2DP profile.

Answer (score 6):

I made it work the following way :

**Before going further :**

- Update your system (I'm running 13.10)
- Remove blueman
- Install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`, `pavucontrol` (Utility to set up
  pulseaudio) and make sure `bluez` is installed
- Remove any "Disable=Socket" or "Enable=Socket" entry in file `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`
  (edit with `sudo`)

**Steps :**

1. Put device in pairing mode (even if already paired)
2. Pair the device with your system using default bluetooth manager (blueman should have been removed) or if already paired go to step 3
3. Select A2DP or Audio Sink connection for the paired device. 
   If it fails try "sudo hciconfig hci0 reset" (where hci0 is your bluetooth device) check scan is ok with hcitool scan then retry this step (do hciconfig -piscan to identify your bluetooth device)
4. With pavutools, select a2dp in "configuration" tab and your device in "Playback" tab / If a2dp is not selected, try `pactl list cards short" to get your device id (1,2,3..)` then do `pactl set-card-profile X a2dp` where X is your device id
5. If it fails, restart `avahi-daemon` / bluetooth service and reset device through `hciconfig hci0 reset`. Check if scan is ok with `hcitool scan`. Then do steps 3 and 4

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Quick questions: #3: "select A2DP or Audio Sink connection"... where from? #4 pavutools is apparently depreciated in jaunty & googling find nothing for installing it. I assume you don't mean Pulse Audio Volume Controls themselves?
Thanks!

Comment: I've tried a number of different workarounds for this issue and so far this is the only one that has worked reliably. Thank you.

Comment: I used a similar approach to this one (my headset is Sony ZX770BN), but `$ sdptool search --bdaddr local a2snk` only returned `Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory`.
I found a solution on the Arch linux forums that worked (I simply edited the systemd service file for bluetooth to include `--compat` in the command line) - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180740

Answer (score 4):

You can try `blueman` application. This app can help you to play audio through A2DP streaming. You just have to mark your device profile as "Audio destination".

To install, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Open it by typing "blueman" in the dash.

<sup>I'll try to update the answer with necessary screenshot later</sup>

Answer (score 0):

see if you have this package installed: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
although the fact that your other BT headset works would suggest so. It is a Mono device though, so it might be subject to different requirements.
Also try referring to my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236188/why-do-i-only-hear-sound-from-the-speakers-with-a2dp-headset-connected), I just posted a solution that works for me.
@Anwar Shah: Removing Blueman was also a part of that solution, just mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blueman with Alsa (packages are much leaner than pulse audio).

Pair and connect as "Audio sink", you'll hear a *'pop-b-b-b'* on the headphones.

find `/etc/alsa.conf` or `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and append this to it;

```
pcm.btheadset {
   type plug
   slave {
       pcm {
           type bluetooth
           device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
           profile "auto"
       }
   }
   hint {
       show on
       description "BT Headset"
   }
}
ctl.btheadset {
  type bluetooth
}
```

The device ID you get from blueman once connected.

e.g `mplayer -ao alsa:device=btheadset mysong.mp3`