# A2DP is broken after system update

Tags: 16.04, headphones, a2dp, bluez

I have Bluetooth Headphones that used to work with my Ubuntu 16.04 but stopped working after the system update.

Now my headphones are working only in headset mode, but when I trying to switch to A2DP, it changes, but there is no any sound then.

`pacmd` shows that A2DP is available

```
index: 2
name: <bluez_card.00_22_37_37_68_74>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
owner module: 23
properties:
    device.description = "JBL E40BT"
    device.string = "00:22:37:37:68:74"
    device.api = "bluez"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.form_factor = "headphone"
    bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_22_37_37_68_74"
    bluez.class = "0x240418"
    bluez.alias = "JBL E40BT"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headphones-bluetooth"
profiles:
    headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 20, available: unknown)
    a2dp_source: High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source) (priority 10, available: no)
    a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 10, available: yes)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
active profile: <a2dp_sink>
sinks:
    bluez_sink.00_22_37_37_68_74/#3: JBL E40BT
sources:
    bluez_sink.00_22_37_37_68_74.monitor/#5: Monitor of JBL E40BT
ports:
    headphone-output: Headphone (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:

    headphone-input: Bluetooth Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
```

In `/var/log/apt/history.log` there are following lines

```
Start-Date: 2016-05-12  10:03:58
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-upgrade-packages' sender=':1.77'
Upgrade: file-roller:amd64 (3.16.4-1ubuntu3, 3.16.5-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2016-05-12  10:04:03

Start-Date: 2016-05-12  10:04:13
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-upgrade-system' sender=':1.77'
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), sudo:amd64 (1.8.16-0ubuntu1, 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (50.0.2661.94-1, 50.0.2661.102-1), udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), libdfu1:amd64 (0.7.0-0ubuntu4, 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.1), libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), systemd-sysv:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu4, 229-4ubuntu5), libfwupd1:amd64 (0.7.0-0ubuntu4, 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.1), file-roller:amd64 (3.16.4-1ubuntu3, 3.16.5-0ubuntu1), fwupd:amd64 (0.7.0-0ubuntu4, 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.1)
End-Date: 2016-05-12  10:05:13
```

It seems to me like there are no related packages, but it caused my headphones to stop working.

I followed some instructions in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287254/ubuntu-13-04-bluetooth-a2dp-does-not-work) and reinstalled bluez, pulseaudio packages, but it did not help me.