# Device Bluetooth 9460/9560 don't connect JBL TUNE500BT Headset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset, bluez, blueman

I've been trying to make my JBL TUNE500BT Headset work on Ubuntu 20.04, installed on Dell Vostro 5490, for two weeks, without success. When connecting the Headset, the service even finds the device, but at the time of connecting, there is a failure.

- I already updated the driver "by hand";
- I have reinstalled blueman and all dependencies;
- I have already entered countless links with guidelines, changing modules and settings.

Has anyone in this group experienced anything like this?
[image]
[image]

I appreciate if anyone can guide me.

I'm not alone: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:8087-0aaa

Comment: * More informations: my bluetooth device is "ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak". I found an update job for the driver (https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:8087-0aaa), but I don't know how to update.

Comment: Do you have any other bluetooth devices (especially headsets) that do work on your computer? I would also test another bluetooth headset (even just a cheap $10 one from Best Buy) to make sure that bluetooth can successfully connect.

Comment: @elijah-cruz-webservices I just tested it with the Bluetooth headset 'Redmi AirDots S' and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have the same Bluetooth adapter and can't pair with my new headphones either: https://askubuntu.com/q/1356008/303

Answer (score 0):

I got my audio to work.  Still trying to get the mic to work.

For most ubuntu users there is an `audio.conf` file in `/etc/bluetooth/`.  For me it was a `main.conf`.

Under `[General]`, include the following lines:

```
Enable=Gateway,Source
Disable=Socket
AutoConnect=true
[Headset]
MaxConnected=1
[A2DP]
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0
```

Then when you go to your bluetooth manager, ensure that you select
`High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)`.  This doesn't solve the problem with the mic though.  These steps comes from the post:
[Ubuntu 13.04 bluetooth A2DP does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287254/ubuntu-13-04-bluetooth-a2dp-does-not-work#318399)