# Problems connecting to Bluetooth headset - 14.04 - problem re-occurs

Tags: wireless, sound, usb, 14.04, bluetooth

Please read the (PS:) at the end of this new post on this specific problem.

I've read carefully [This post](http://goo.gl/1yiK5E) but still have problems to connect to one of my Bluetooth headset.

I have two bluetooth headsets (SHB71150 from philips, and WeSC Piston along with two bluetooth dongles one from Thrust (bluetooth V3 version) and and Belkin one (bluetooth V4 version).

For both dongles and both headsets Philips SHB7150 and WeSC Piston BT Black I get the same result :

The dongle manages to connect to the headset, but I have no further option in the Volume control to uses the Bluetooth device.

PS : Now things are a bit different : When I try to pair (Either the SHB71150 from philips, and WeSC Piston) the little bluetooth button shows that the pairing is being done but a few seconds later, the pairing is lost.

I've read all the posts related to bluetooth and head sets bu did not find a viable solution.

Could any one give me a hand on this new problem?

Comment: Is `module-bluetooth-discover` correctly loaded in pulseaudio? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/414258/successfully-connected-to-a-bluetooth-speaker-but-how-do-i-direct-sound-there for details.

Comment: here is the result of the bt-devile -l command : bt-device -l
Added devices:
WeSC Piston BT black (00:1B:B8:2F:2F:0F)
Philips SHB7150 (00:1E:7C:27:A1:59)

Comment: What do you mean by module-bluetooth-discover correctly loaded in pulse (I'm a newbie in this domain). What I can say is the bluetooh headset seems to appair, but I have no option to control its sound ???

Comment: bt-device -l
Added devices:
WeSC Piston BT black (00:1B:B8:2F:2F:0F)
Philips SHB7150 (00:1E:7C:27:A1:59)        bt-device -i 00:1E:7C:27:A1:59
[00:1E:7C:27:A1:59]
  Name: Philips SHB7150
  Alias: Philips SHB7150 [rw]
  Address: 00:1E:7C:27:A1:59
  Icon: audio-card
  Class: 0x240404
  Paired: 1
  Trusted: 1 [rw]
  Blocked: 0 [rw]
  Connected: 1
  UUIDs: [Headset, AudioSink, AVRemoteControl, Handsfree, PnPInformation]

Comment: I've added the following lines to /etc/pulse/default.pa ;### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif. In fact the command :  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover works fine and allows me to add the headset to the available output, but only once.. This is not a long term solution

Comment: I remove the lines ### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware .ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so load-module module-bluetooth-discover .endif from  the /etc/pulse/default.pa file as it does'nt brinh any solution

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem fixed it with:

```
pactl list cards short
```

to get the device id, then I did:

```
pactl set-card-profile X a2dp
```

where X is your device id

found it by reading
[No A2DP streaming audio from 12.04 to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203272/no-a2dp-streaming-audio-from-12-04-to-bluetooth-headset)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. http://askubuntu.com/a/519201/88802

Comment: pactl list cards short gives me :
0 alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1 module-alsa-card.c
1 alsa_card.usb-045e_USB_camera-01-camera module-alsa-card.c
2 alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 module-alsa-card.c
but I do not understand what to do with your pactl set-card-profile X a2dp command

Comment: I already tried to change my USB bluetooth dongle from a Belkin to a Thrust one, to change the USB port. Nothing works and I am 100% sure it worked perfectly some weeks ago.