# a2dp bluetooth problem on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, a2dp

I have a pair of Bose AE2w headphones that initially connect fine with Bluetooth on 14.04. I can select the headphones and choose A2DP output, and everything works.

If the connection times out due to inactivity or from hibernation, and I reactivate the headphones, the Bluetooth connection is re-established, but A2DP does not work only HSP.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This post "may" help http://askubuntu.com/questions/319871/bluetooth-speaker-preferred-mode-high-fidelity-playback-a2dp-is-not-getting

Comment: I will try the suggestion that is in that post to see if it makes any difference, but it won't be a solution, because I have a headset, whereas the ...871 post is someone with a speaker.  So, I want to be able to switch between a2dp and hsp depending on what I am doing.

Comment: After trying the "Disable=Heaset" setting from the suggested post, the a2dp option still does not work after a timeout.

Comment: I can't add an answer, so let me tell you here what worked for me: (1) install BLUEMAN (http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/blueman); (2) right click on the device + click "Audio Sink"; (3) after it confirms that the configuration went through, check the "Audio Profile"... In my case it already had the "A2DP" selected and working! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I will try blueman this week and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in other tread... it worked for me:

Had the same problem fixed it with:

```
pactl list cards short
```

to get the device id. 
Then I did

```
pactl set-card-profile x a2dp
```

where X is your device id.

found it by reading
[No A2DP streaming audio from 12.04 to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203272/no-a2dp-streaming-audio-from-12-04-to-bluetooth-headset)

Comment: Missed the email that alerted me to this answer, but followed the recommendations in the link provided and also checked a couple of other answers under that question, but still no success.  There is improvement in that if I disable the bluetooth connection to the headset in system settings, I can re-enable it later and have it work.  But if it times out the connection or the connection is lost due to hibernation or suspension, then I still have to remove and re-pair the headset to get A2DP sound.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. =/ I get a "Failure: Input/Output error".

Comment: @Nigini have you found a solution ?