# How to keep bluetooth headphones from turning off?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 16.10, headphones, timeout

Ever since I've had my [JBL-E50BT](http://www.jbl.com/wireless-headphones/SYNCHROS+E50BT.html) headphones I've been struggling to make them work properly on Ubuntu.

For instance every time I connect them, I have to switch the audio profile to HSP/HFP, disconnect, reconnect and switch back to A2DP before they will make any sound with A2DP. But it's something I can live with.

The JBL headphones have a "feature" that turns them off after no sound is played for n minutes, probably to preserve power. I'm not sure of the exact time, but it's something around 15-30 minutes.

Previously my Ubuntu system kept the headphones from idling, and a static noise could be heard from the headphones at any time it was connected. But ever since an update I did 2 weeks ago (not a dist upgrade) this does not seem to happen anymore.
Right now, when sound is not playing, the system will stop outputting sound after 5 seconds and the headphones will go into idle-mode. No noise is then heard out of the headphones.

My question is: How do I prevent my headphones from going into idle-mode, answers to resolve issue with connecting the headphones would also be appreciated, as this will make reconnecting them after the timout a lot less annoying.

I am not concerned about the battery of the headphones, they can easily last a full work day playing music.

Update:

As suggested by @MadMike I tried the commands from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516509/a2dp-bluetooth-problem-on-14-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B04) post.

```
$ pactl list cards short

0       alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0      module-alsa-card.c
1       alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0      module-alsa-card.c
4       bluez_card.00_22_37_3F_C9_A4    module-bluez5-device.c

$ pactl set-card-profile 4 a2dp
Failure: No such entity
```

I'm not sure what to do with this result.

Comment: Does this question address part of your issue? http://askubuntu.com/questions/516509/a2dp-bluetooth-problem-on-14-04

Comment: @MadMike thanks for your suggestion, but the answer you linked doesn't seem to work on my system. The command posted in the answer outputs `Failure: No such entity`, no matter what I input for X (device ID).

Comment: This is importent information and should be part of your question. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/894860/edit) your question. Add what you did and add the result.

Comment: @MadMike Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue with the above command, (`pactl set-card-profile 4 a2dp`), is that you do not have the correct profile name.
Run `pactl list cards`. Then find your Bluetooth device. For example, mine is:
`Card #3
    Name: bluez_card.00_02_5B_01_3C_3B`
Next find the `Profiles:` section. The profile I enable on my system is `a2dp_sink`. So my command to enable that profile is:
`pactl set-card-profile 3 a2dp_sink`

However, instead of the index number, I would recommend using the card name instead. The index number can change.
If you run:
`~$ pactl set-card-profile
You have to specify a card name/index and a profile name`
you get the above message. So, in my case, I would use:
`pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.00_02_5B_01_3C_3B a2dp_sink`