# "Connection failed: Stream setup failed" when using A2DP

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I'm trying to use my PC as a A2DP sink for my Nexus 7, but I can't seem to connect.

The bluetooth dongle I'm using is the ASUS-BT211

[image: Error:Bluetooth]

**Things that I have tried already:**

- Adding Source to the pulseaudio "Enable" line.
- Adding Socket to the pulseaudio "Disable" line.
- Installing all bluetooth packages.

But still, it's not fixed.

Its not an adapter problem. It works fine in windows.

Comment: Did you try if this still works? http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver

Comment: nope, it does not work :(

Comment: Still reproducible?

Comment: I don't quite agree that this question should be closed as being very specific.  This is a common problem with many bluetooth setups and headsets, and it seems the most common fix is that the pulseaudio bluetooth module isn't loaded.  You can fix this by first running:

pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with my device. I own the bh-905i nokia headset and at first i wasn't even able to pair it, using my bluetooth dongle. This started happening after updating Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 using livecd. My kernel is up-to-date.
So:
->The device was detected by blueman, but couldn't pair by any means.
->After adding 'Enable = Socket' to the General section of  /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf, i could pair it, but wasn't able to use a2dp stream. The error was "failed to change profile to a2dp".
->the headset appeared on the output tab, but it did not work at all (even though it was paired).

After struggling around a lot, i did this:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo killall pulseaudio
```

restarted pulseaudio   (alt+F2 pulseaudio)

then i added these lines in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`

> in [General] 
>   Disable=Socket
>
> in [Headset] 
>   changed HFP value to 
>   HFP=false
>
> and in [A2DP]
>   SBCSources=1
>   and MPEG12Sources=0

then i restarted the bluetooth:

```
sudo restart bluetooth
```

and it WORKS now.

Unfortunately, if i disconnect the headset during the session i have to restart alsa and pulseaudio before trying to connect again.

Also, i change the profile to a2dp ONLY on blueman, because if i try to do that at the output tab of the sound manager (alsa, i think), i fail.

Bear with me, please, i am not an expert. And english isn't my first language.
good luck!

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(