# Can't send audio to Amazon Echo via Bluetooth

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have an Amazon Echo and a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.1. I can successfully pair the device via Bluetooth (the Echo says `Now connected to <my machine's name>`), but when I test the sound, nothing is heard. The volumes are high enough and other devices can connect to the Echo just fine.

[image: No sound through the Echo]

Here's the `dmesg` output:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   12.419477] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   12.419491] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.419494] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.419497] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.419502] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.473236] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[   12.480889] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   12.839251] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   13.386452] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.386456] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.386460] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.473284] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.473292] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.473297] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[10944.651128] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[10944.651133] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[10944.977821] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[24061.878085] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[24061.887184] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[24062.211121] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[24072.874829] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[24072.874835] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[24073.196858] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[45209.076985]  iwlwifi videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 serio_raw videobuf2_core btrtl btbcm btintel input_leds bluetooth snd_hda_codec_realtek(OE) snd_hda_codec_generic(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi(OE) v4l2_common snd_seq_midi joydev cfg80211 snd_seq_midi_event videodev media snd_hda_intel(OE) snd_hda_codec(OE) snd_hda_core(OE) snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp snd_seq mei_me mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd elan_i2c int3403_thermal 8250_fintek soundcore 8250_dw i2c_designware_platform dw_dmac snd_soc_sst_acpi i2c_designware_core dell_smo8800 dw_dmac_core processor_thermal_device spi_pxa2xx_platform int3402_thermal int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel intel_soc_dts_iosf dell_rbtn acpi_als mac_hid acpi_pad kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4
[55174.636122] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[55174.646073] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[55174.970198] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[55181.295879] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[55181.295922] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[55181.670006] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[56551.946597] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[56551.955475] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[56552.282610] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[98502.038807] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[98502.038816] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[98502.356833] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[107908.657215] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[107908.657298] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[107908.985251] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[109042.464364] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[109042.464372] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[109042.782838] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[109052.807963] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[109052.807968] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[109053.127969] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[127570.876446] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[127570.953632] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[127571.270715] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Answer (score 6):

I also have this problem.  Pairing and sending audio to other bluetooth speakers works. Pairing works to Amazon Echo but no sound is ever heard. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial), which was upgraded from 15.10 today (Wily) which in turn was upgraded from 14.04 LTS (Trusty). (I mention this as I wonder if the problem may be specific to upgrade paths vs. fresh installs.)

I believe the problem is related to the fact that *pulseaudio* pairs the device as a headset rather than just a speaker. This requires *a2dp*, and that, for me, appears to be where the failure is occurring.

For example, when I pair to my Bose SoundLink II (which works and has since 14.04), *dmesg* shows:

```
Feb 28 10:57:04 n1 bluetoothd[1025]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_0C_8A_58_F6_CA/fd2: fd(22) ready
Feb 28 10:57:04 n1 bluetoothd[1025]: No pending request, ignoring message
Feb 28 10:57:04 n1 kernel: [ 1053.711796] input: 00:0C:8A:58:F6:CA as /devices/virtual/input/input20
```

HOWEVER, when I pair to my Amazon Echo, *dmesg* reports:

```
Feb 28 10:59:05 n1 bluetoothd[1025]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 50:F5:DA:A6:3F:EA: Device or resource busy
Feb 28 10:59:05 n1 bluetoothd[1025]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_50_F5_DA_A6_3F_EA/fd3: fd(22) ready
Feb 28 10:59:05 n1 kernel: [ 1174.849178] input: 50:F5:DA:A6:3F:EA as /devices/virtual/input/input21
```

The key line in the above output is the first one, where a2dp reports that the device or resource is busy.

I've hunted around to find a resolution, but so far no luck.  The answer proposed by MrUser in discussion found at [Question #440386](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440386/bluetoothd-bluez-5-wont-connect-with-any-devices) suggests that the problem may be related to "...**a2dp was moved out of the BlueZ stack and into GStreamer**" and that he found some success by compiling pulseaudio 5.x himself.  However, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS uses pulseaudio 8.0, not 5.x and, moreover, the error message above suggests pulseaudio on my system **does** support a2dp but that a2dp for some reason cannot access the device after bluetoothd has connected it.

This leads me to believe the problem **might be due to some problem with permissions or access**, but I cannot be sure.

The discussion found at [Question #763539](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763539/bluetooth-speaker-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04) and elsewhere suggest that switching to HSP/HFP mode and then back to A2DP mode resolves the problem, but that is for KDE (i.e., Kubuntu).  I have tried to using the a2dp.py script provide by @pylover posted there.  It runs fine, but the a2dp "device or resource busy" error still occurs and the problem is not resolved.

If can find time, I will turn on Bluetooth Debugging (as described on [Ubuntu's Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth)) and report back  what I find.  My sense is that this problem can be fixed and that the issue is a simple one, but precisely tracking down the point of failure and making a correction is non-trivial.

If anyone else has insights into this problem and possible resolutions, I'd be most grateful to hear.

Comment: I should also note that, similear to what Hedley noted, mplayer hangs up when I am connected to the Amazon Echo.  More specifically, VLC, Kodi, and others play video just fine, but there's no sound.  Mplayer, on the other hand, shows the first video frame but then hangs.

Comment: **Update**: Running bluetoothd with debugging enabled (i.e., -d option) provided no new information.  Running btmon while connecting the Amazon Echo showed no error messages and made no reference to A2DP.

Comment: Point of information, this problem occurs on arch linux as well. (same a2dp-source profile connect failed device or resource busy lines)

Comment: **Update:** I've finally gotten around to reporting this bug to Ubuntu.  Here's the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1691556).If you use Ubuntu, kindly login there click on "Yes, this bug affects me." to help increase the bug's priority.  If you use ArchLinux or know this to be a problem on other distributions, you can report the issue to those distros as well (easily by referring here and to the Ubuntu bug report), if you are so kindly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was in sound settings. At first, I could connect, but no sound. In the sound settings, I changed the 'output device' drop-down box to the default, then back to my Echo manually. YouTube video clicked right in.