# kubuntu: connect to android device with bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)") and want to connect my Xiaomi MI5 mobile with bluetooth, so I can transfer files to and from the phone; I am beginning to think it may not be possible.

I found this already: [bluetoothd (BlueZ 5) won't connect with any devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440386/bluetoothd-bluez-5-wont-connect-with-any-devices) - however, it seems to be a different problem from mine. I have very little experience with bluetooth, so I could use some help, please.

Having restarted bluetoothd with debugoutput, I see the following when I try to pair from the mobile:

```
Mar  5 11:26:08 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A connected eir_len 16
Mar  5 11:26:09 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:user_confirm_request_callback() hci0 AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A confirm_hint 0
Mar  5 11:26:09 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:new_auth() Requesting agent authentication for AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A
Mar  5 11:26:09 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x564d7482d880: ref=2
Mar  5 11:26:09 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/agent.c:agent_request_confirmation() Calling Agent.RequestConfirmation: name=:1.70, path=/modules/bluedevil/Agent, passkey=087258
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A type 0 status 0x5
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x05
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/agent.c:send_cancel_request() Sending Cancel request to :1.70, /modules/bluedevil/Agent
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:device_cancel_authentication() Canceling authentication request for AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x564d7482d880: ref=1
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 5
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A disconnected, reason 3
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 3
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A type 0 status 0xe
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x0e
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 14
Mar  5 11:26:39 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
```

And if I try to connect from the PC:

```
Mar  5 11:35:52 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: src/device.c:connect_profiles() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_C1_EE_1B_80_5A (all), client :1.88
Mar  5 11:35:52 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:a2dp_source_connect() path /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_C1_EE_1B_80_5A
Mar  5 11:35:52 GR-00258 bluetoothd[13393]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for AC:C1:EE:1B:80:5A: Protocol not available
```

Comment: Same issue for me. I have a Realtek 8822 bluetooth adapter in a Asus TUF Gaming FA506II on Archlinux