# iPhone 6 as Bluetooth A2DP Source in 15.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, iphone, bluez

I've tried connecting my iPhone 6 as a bluetooth A2DP source (i.e. stream music from it) to my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop (a Dell Latitude E6440), but I can't get it to show up under "Choose a device for sound input" under "Input" in "Sound Settings".

I tried with my Android phone (Sony Xperia Z3 Compact) and it showed up without any problem.

I tried Googling around for a solution to this, but so far I can't find a reason why the iPhone would not show up, nor a workaround to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer to the follwing question is a bit older but I think it should still work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem solved itself over time, without me doing anything (other than installing the normal updates). My iPhone now appears as an Input device in sound settings.