# Use ubuntu as bluetooth receiver

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to make ubuntu detect and connect to a bluetooth transmitter. It does not work by default with the bluetooth setting dialog on 17.04

I have found [Can I use my computer as an A2DP receiver / bluetooth speaker?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2573/350004) which is rather old as I am using 17.04 and this does not work here.

There is no `/etc/bluetooh/audio.conf` file. I have tried to add the line `Enable=Source` in the various file I found in /etc/bluetooth (and restart bluetooth daemon each time with `systemctl restart bluetooth`) and it had no effect. And finally create a /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf file with the lines.

I can not see the bluetooth transmitter, and can't connect to it obviously

How can I make ubuntu act as a receiver and connect to my audio bluetooth transmetter ?

Does it work for you as described in other thread, meaning it is an issue with the transmitter TT-BA07 taotronics or not ?

**Edit:**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:c530 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: F8:2F:A8:D3:88:F8  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:6907 acl:0 sco:0 events:450 errors:0
    TX bytes:35626 acl:0 sco:0 commands:420 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ChromeLinux_A0D5'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x121
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)


$ journalctl -b -u bluetooth
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-03-31 08:40:15 CEST, end at Sat 2017-09-30 22:57:16 CEST. --
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Starting SDP server
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Sap driver initialization failed.
sept. 30 13:17:14 titan bluetoothd[1691]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
sept. 30 13:17:20 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
sept. 30 13:17:20 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
sept. 30 13:17:26 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
sept. 30 13:17:26 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
sept. 30 13:17:30 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.102 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
sept. 30 13:17:30 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.102 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
sept. 30 14:13:49 titan bluetoothd[1691]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)

$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[   14.134899] usb 3-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[   14.241204] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.241228] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.241233] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.241235] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.241246] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.404113] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   14.420127] Bluetooth: hci0: ChromeLinux_A0D5
[   14.420133] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0289
[   15.139173] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0289
[   15.155169] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 Generic USB Class 2 NonUHE @ 20 MHz
[   22.012621] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.012623] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.012628] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   28.199744] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   28.199754] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   28.199761] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1164.142711] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) rfcomm cmac bnep binfmt_misc xfs crypto_simd glue_helper algif_skcipher af_alg arc4 dell_wmi sparse_keymap nls_iso8859_1 dell_laptop dell_smbios dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp uvcvideo snd_hda_codec_hdmi videobuf2_vmalloc kvm_intel videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic rtsx_usb_ms kvm snd_hda_intel irqbypass memstick videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_core crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec videodev snd_hda_core btusb snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate btrtl btbcm intel_rapl_perf media snd_pcm btintel bluetooth snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi input_leds serio_raw ath9k_htc ath9k_common ath9k_hw joydev ath wl(POE)
[...]
```

I have a chromecast but I don't know my bluetooth adapter ended up being named like the chromecast I have.... (Oh it's a bug in chrome ????)

Comment: Can Ubuntu detect other bluetooth devices in pairing mode and can other devices detect the transmitter when it is in pairing mode?

Comment: Yes ubuntu can detect other device like headset or speaker. Yes the transmitter is seen by speaker when in pairing mode.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: The chromelinux name is normal but I am not sure why you can't find or pair with the transmitter in Ubuntu.  I didn't have to make any changes to send audio from my phone to my Ubuntu laptop- A2DP audio from youtube video

Comment: Ok. It did not tought on doing that. And in fact, I am able to connect and pair my android tablet with my PC. But sound is choppy. But at least it almost works.